# Consuming RESTful C# Web Service through Java Android

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, rest

**Dears,**

I know that the title seems popular and easy but what I'm facing is too strange.

Simply, I have a RESTful C# .NET 4.0 web service published on the server, and I want to consume it through Java in my Android application, easy?

**The problem is:** whenever I call the .NET web service and get the response, java could not parse the return string into Json.

**Error message:**

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {lhs:"1 Euro",rhs: "1.3711 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
at com.itrack21.mobileapp.LoginActivity.getUserInfo(LoginActivity.java:151)
at com.itrack21.mobileapp.LoginActivity$1$1.run(LoginActivity.java:114)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164d700)
```

**Java Code:**

```
public void getRate(String link) {

        try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream str = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(str);
                BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line=new String();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while( (line=bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String rhs = "";
            try {
                rhs = obj.getString("rhs");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("getRate","Converted Currency = " + rhs.toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Debugging:

I did many debugging scenarios but with no luck, here I will use strangest one to describe the problem.

1. I use my java code to consume Google web service for currency converting using the following link `http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?EUR` and I got the response as follows: `{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "0.726321906 Euros",error: "",icc: true}`. And here my code is working perfectly.
2. I copy exact Json value return from Google web service and working fine with my code, and return it as a HARD CODED String in my RESTful C# service as follows:

**C# Code:**

```
public string GetInfo()
{
return "{lhs:\"1 Euro\",rhs: \"1.3711 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}";
}
```

1. I request my C# .NET web service using the same code used to invoke Google web service bu I got error listed above `org.json.JSONException: Value {lhs:"1 Euro",rhs: "1.3711 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)`.
2. When I copy and paste the return value into my code as a HARD CODE, it works just fine.

   ```
   JSONObject obj = null;
   try {
       obj = new JSONObject("{lhs:\"1 Euro\",rhs: \"1.3711 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}");
   } catch (JSONException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Many "Crazy" debugging scenario done including changing the server itself, but with no luck.

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Regards,

Comment: If it works with google then your code seems to be ok, use your own server and it fails... What has changed? The source of data, not your code. Have you checked what your service _realy_ returns? Is it in the same format as you expect? Hint: use fiddler to figure it out

Comment: Could you copy here how the buffer.toString() looks like? Thanks

Comment: `Buffer look like:(24401): "{lhs:\"1 Euro\",rhs: \"1.3711 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}"` exactly. @lboshuizen, as I told you, I copied the string as it is to my C# function, and when I use it through any browser either Chrome, Firefox or IE, all results are same.

Comment: From a browser ok, but what, and how, is requested by and returned to the android app?

Comment: @lboshuizen, I print the buffer return before this line  `obj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());` and it look like `Buffer look like:(24401): "{lhs:\"1 Euro\",rhs: \"1.3711 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}"` what do you think?

Comment: What's in this line: getUserInfo(LoginActivity.java:151)? Java code and stack trace reference a different function.

Comment: This name `getUserInfo` is the name of my method in my code, here I change it to `getRate` for simplifying the problem, but the have same logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging process, I got the cause, and then the solution. Here we go:

1. Visit [Google Maps Web Service](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling) through Chrome browser, and you will get Json response. For debugging purpose, right click on page and select `View page source`. Note that the string of Json is pure Json with no additions.
2. When you repeat same procedure with the C# .NET response through Chrome browser, you will notice that the response is NOT pure Json, it is surrounded by this: `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{JSON String HERE}</string>`.

**Solution:**

To remove this string surrounding the response, you have to return Json string as `System.IO.Stream`. Here the required code changes:

```
public System.IO.Stream GetInfo()
{
    OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
    context.ContentType = "text/plain";
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("{lhs:\"1 Euro\",rhs: \"1.3711 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}"));
}
```

This solution works fine with me, but is it optimal solution? converting from object to Json, and then from Json string to bytes is little overhead, what do think? suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, you need to wrap the keys in quotation marks too. So for this:

`{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "0.726321906 Euros",error: "",icc: true}`,

you will have to do this:

`{"lhs": "1 U.S. dollar","rhs": "0.726321906 Euros","error": "","icc": "true"}`

You can check your JSON online at : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hi, I already did what you suggest while I'm debugging specially that I use .NET JavaScript Serializer as follows: `string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyObject);` and it gives same error above. Also, if string returned by Google is NOT valid Json, why the Java code accept it?

Comment: Are you using MVC Controllers or Web API Controllers?

Comment: I guess I'm using Web API controllers :/

Comment: does your controller extend `Controller` or `ApiController`, `Controller` is the MVC class and `ApiController` is for WebAPI. If your controller is a WebAPI controller, don't serialize the object, just return it, WebAPI does the rest.